# How to express "We the ...", "We who are ..."

Tags: grammar

I am having a bad time trying figure out how to say this.

The sentence I am trying to make is "We the westerners, think that the way Japanese people take a bath it's a bit weird. I guess it's the cultural difference right".

The hardest for me it's saying "we the 'something'".

What I could come up with so far is:

> 僕ら西洋人は「日本人が入浴するの方法がちょっと変だ」と思いますよ。やっぱり文化的な違いですね

Please correct me, if there are any other points that are wrong or sound unnatural.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: maybe "僕のように西洋人"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

僕ら西洋人 is natural and 私達西洋人 is also appropriate. 僕のように西洋人 is unnatural but 僕のような西洋人 make sense and it means "a westerner like me".

I correct your sentence more natural like 僕ら西洋人は、日本人の入浴の仕方はちょっと変だと思います。やっぱり文化的な違いからかな。「」 isn't necessary.

Comment: there's no の in between 僕ら/僕たち and 西洋人？

Comment: Yes, 僕らの西洋人 means "our  westerners" but it is odd, isn't it? However 西洋人の僕ら means "We the westerners" and the same as 僕ら西洋人.

Comment: I think you could also use 我々西洋人